# Generic Method Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type X

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I am new to creating generic methods and have come across casting issues.

The following is a class library for communicating with an API. The object I am trying to cast to lives in my main application, which might be the issue but I do not know. What might I be doing wrong?

```
public T GetRequest<T>(Authentication auth, string api)
{
     var restClient = new RestClient(Constants.Api.Client);

     var restRequest = new RestRequest(api, Method.GET);
     SetParameters(restRequest, auth);

     var restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

     return JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<T>(restResponse.Content, (T)new object());
}
```

Comment: In future, please include the *exact* error message within the body of your question, explain whether it's a compile-time error or an exception, and indicate exactly where you're getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The object I am trying to cast to lives in my main application

It's not entirely clear what you mean by that, but the object you're trying to cast is just an instance of `System.Object`:

```
(T)new object()
```

That can *never* work unless `T` itself is `object`.

The problem here appears to be that you're trying to use a method designed for working with anonymous types (so the second parameter is present as an "example" to make type inference work) - but with a type which *isn't* anonymous (`T`).

I suspect you just want:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(restResponse.Content);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.. that was pretty simple. The whole DeserializeAnonymousType thing had me trying anything to make it clear of errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your method last line `(T)new object()` is a problem. This makes no sense. You're creating new instance of `System.Object` and trying to cast it to `T` where `T` could be anything. Your method is going to succeed only when called with generic parameter `T` as `System.Object`. For example `GetRequest<object>(...)` will pass, otherwise it will fail.

Am not sure what you're trying to achieve here. If you can provide more info it will be easy to help.